# Find Same Duplicate Max Value Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, index-match

So i try return value from table which has same percentage using Index match, but it return the same value twice instead of another value that has the same percentage
Here is my Excel View, is there any help for my problem?

[Here is my excel formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMMYt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxOZ3.png)

Comment: Cannot get the problem with your explanations and the screenshot.  Pls show your formula at least.

Comment: I found out that INDEX/Match only return the value of first line, is there any way to solve that?

Comment: i have provide the formula sir

Comment: @OzgunSenyuva i have provided the formula sir

Comment: Maybe you can try `large` function.  But you can always copy them manually and sort by percentages.  this looks much easier.

Comment: i just try to automate it by formula..., so it will be more easier when someone later use my sheet...,can u pliss explain more about large function

Comment: Please refer to [ask] a question with an [mcve]. It's adviced to use simplified markdown sample data with your expected result. So much harder to work from cluttered screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

1st: you can't and shouldn't use Match(...,...,-1) in unsorted data, use Match(...,...,0) only

2nd: you can't search for the 2nd similar because... the program has no way of  knowing there are 2|3... similar objects. So you must get the positions of ranks when sorting them, and then use that position to get the score and value you want with index(). So Sorting and getting the Position (or ROW()) must be done same time.

3rd: the way to do this is with Matrix formulas that work for on a pre-specified number of cells: So you can look in a table of 200 elements for 10 results and have provision to avoid errors if results are <10, but you'll never get 11. Also *Hide* the column with the positions to gain clarity...

try this formula:

= LARGE( ROUND( OFFSET(**$B$3**,,,**$G$1**)*1000,0)**100* + ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,**$G$1**)),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,**$G$2**)) )

to get a sorted list from column B Starting w **B3** with N rows (N specified in **G1**) and look for m results (m specified in **g2**). Offcourse adjust the **bolds** as needed for your project

4th: Enter the formula in a Column that you will hide, with ctrl+shft+Enter (to enter as matrix) and expand it in as many cells as the results you expect (in the example **2**) by selecting them starting with the cell with Array-formula, then F2 (to edit formula) and ctrl+sht+enter. Mind that Arrays can only be EXPANDED, if you want to shrink it you have to delete it and rebuild it...

5th: get the Index with **=MOD( ... ,*100*)** ,where ... are the results from steps 3&4

---

1ST AGAIN: Another simple solution (*not to my Liking). Within your Match(item,range,-1) you should compare item with previous item and use Offset. In your formula you can write:
=Index($C$12:$C$23, Match(DF19, **Offset(** $CQ$12:$CQ$23 **,if(DF19=DF18, Match(DF19,$CQ$12:$CQ$23,0),0)** ,-1) ))
thus pushing the search matrix further down to avoid finding the same.
(added code with BOLD, rest should be same to your original code)

Comment: If you have static numbers then replace G1 and G2 with them, Or entierly the "OFFSET($B$3,,,$G$1)" and "OFFSET($A$1,,,$G$2)" parts: Say g1=50 and g2=10 the replace as "OFFSET($B$3,,,50)" and "OFFSET($A$1,,,10)"  ... OR completely with "$B$3:$B$52"  and  "$A$1:$A$10" respectively...

Comment: yet i still recieve #Value error..

Comment: mind how you enter the MATRIX formulas and how you expand them (that is beyond explaining here). The code came from a working demo...

Comment: Look after Last edit for a 2nd solution [1st Again], not my best but lot easier to implement on you existing code